# Cant get my task listed in sbt tasks

Tags: scala, sbt

I have added this task in Build.scala:

```
  object SchemaTasks {
    lazy val generateSchema = inputKey[Unit]("schema generation job")
    lazy val tasks = Seq(sbt.Keys.fork in generateSchema := true,
                     fullRunInputTask(generateSchema,Compile, "schema.generate.GenerateSchema", "desc", "false"),
                     fullRunInputTask(generateSchema,Compile, "schema.generate.GenerateSchema"))

  }
```

I did `sbt compile` followed by `sbt tasks` but my task is not getting listed, also i am getting an error if i run this task,

```
sbt generateSchema
```

> [info] Loading project definition from
>   /Users/arun/components/force/holonet/project [info] Set current
>   project to holonet (in build
>   file:/Users/arun/components/force/holonet/) [error] Not a valid
>   command: generateSchema [error] Not a valid project ID: generateSchema
>   [error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration) [error] Not a
>   valid key: generateSchema (similar: generateManPages,
>   generate-man-pages) [error] generateSchema [error]

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks folks, i found the issue. The missing part was i didnt add this object to settings, seems it needs to be integrated with project settings.

```
settings = commonSettings ++ SchemaTasks.tasks ++ Seq(
libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.dataModel,
```

Now it works fine.